# Visual Studio Warning "Content is not allowed" in ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, javascript, visual-studio-2008, devexpress

I am just started working as a programmer last month, so there will be plenty of newbie question come from me, stay tuned... I am now working on modify the provided template (from DevExpress) to create new web form using ASP.NET 2.0 on Visual Studio 2008.

While the functionality of that web form is there, I am in the process of get rid of ninety something warning message, most of them come from the provided template.

One of them puzzled me for a while is this one:
"Warning    75  Content is not allowed between the opening and closing tags for element 'ClientSideEvents'."

And here is the code:

```
<dxe:ASPxListBox id="edtMultiResource" runat="server" width="100%" 
SelectionMode="CheckColumn" DataSource='<%# ResourceDataSource %>' Border-BorderWidth="0">
    <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="function(s, e) {
    var resourceNames = new Array();
        var items = s.GetSelectedItems();
        var count = items.length;
        if (count > 0) {
            for(var i=0; i<count; i++) 
                _aspxArrayPush(resourceNames, items[i].text);
        }
        else
            _aspxArrayPush(resourceNames, ddResource.cp_Caption_ResourceNone);
        ddResource.SetValue(resourceNames.join(', '));
    }"></ClientSideEvents>
</dxe:ASPxListBox>
```

I couldn't see anything wrong with the code myself, so please help me out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chetan Sastry was on the right track in his answer that he deleted. The script that you have put in the HTML attribute is not HTML encoded.

You have to encode any characters that have a special meaning in HTML, like `<`, `>`, `&` and the `"` delimiters for the attribute value:

```
<dxe:ASPxListBox id="edtMultiResource" runat="server" width="100%" 
SelectionMode="CheckColumn" DataSource='<%# ResourceDataSource %>' Border-BorderWidth="0">
                                <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="function(s, e) {
                                var resourceNames = new Array();
                                    var items = s.GetSelectedItems();
                                    var count = items.length;
                                    if (count &gt; 0) {
                                        for(var i=0; i&lt;count; i++) 
                                            _aspxArrayPush(resourceNames, items[i].text);
                                    }
                                    else
                                        _aspxArrayPush(resourceNames, ddResource.cp_Caption_ResourceNone);
                                    ddResource.SetValue(resourceNames.join(', '));
                                }"></ClientSideEvents>
                            </dxe:ASPxListBox>
```

Comment: Thank you Guffa, that works!

So I think it will be better if I put the javaScript code in separate file?

Comment: @pstar: Yes, if you create a function in a script tag or in a separate file, you don't have to HTML encode it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the tag configuration from

```
<ClientSideEvents property="value"></ClientSideEvents>
```

to

```
<ClientSideEvents property="value" />
```

Comment: Thank you Adam, I think this one will work, and I think tried it myself before. I am not sure but think that wouldn't pass validator?